# Bootstrap hamburgermenu (collapse in) visibility issue on IOS (Safari)

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-safari, responsive

I have a responsive webapp which uses bootstrap. When mobile-size a hamburger menu shows in the header.

When clicked on a pc/mac/android phone it displays correctly.. But when clicked with iOS-Safari, it shows up for a quarter of a second, and hides again. I suspect this is a height or z-index issue but I'm not sure, and I have not been able to solve it.

You can try for yourself on [www.gjovikhk.no](http://www.gjovikhk.no).

Anyways.. here is the HTML code for the header and menu :

```
<div id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div id="logo" class="logo-placeholder">
                        <a href='Default.aspx'>
                            <img runat="server" id="imgClubLogo" src="" /></a>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="z-index:9999999999">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left menu-row" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                        <li class="nav">
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkLoginMobile" Text="Login" href="/Login" />
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav">
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" href="/ViewAboutUs" ID="lnkAboutUsMobile" Text="Om GHK" />
                        </li>


                        <li class="nav">
                            <a href="#" runat="server" id="lnkPersonalMobile" style="display: none"><i style="padding-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></i>Mitt lag</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav">
                            <a href="Forum.aspx?type=1" runat="server" id="lnkCoachForumMobile" style="display: none"><i style="padding-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty gly-spin"></i>&nbsp;Trenerforum</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav">
                            <div style="float: left; color: lightyellow; width: 18px; padding-top: 16px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" runat="server" id="starPersonalMobile" clientidmode="Static" visible="False">&nbsp;</div>
                            <div style="float: left">
                                <div class="dropdown" runat="server" id="ddlPersonalMobile" clientidmode="Static" visible="False" style="display: inline-block">
                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="menu3mobile" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:darkgreen!important">
                                        Mine lag
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                                        <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvCoachesTeamsMobile" ItemType="Servicelayer.Team" OnItemCommand="lvTeams_OnItemCommand">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <li role="presentation">
                                                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkNavDep" style="color:darkgreen!important" Text='<%# Item.Name %>' CommandArgument='<%# Item.Id %>' CommandName="NavigateToTeam" />
                                                </li>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:ListView>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav">
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" href="/TeamOverview" ID="lnkTeamOverview" Text="Lag" />
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav">
                            <asp:LinkButton Visible="False" runat="server" href="/AdminPage" ID="lnkAdminPage" Text="Admin" />
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav" style="display: none">
                            <asp:LinkButton Visible="False" runat="server" href="/EventCalendar" ID="lnkTeamOverviewMobile" Text="Eventkalender" />
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav">
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkLogoutMobile" Text="Logg ut" OnClick="lnkLogoutMobile_OnClick" Visible="False" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
                <div class="navbar-icon-topright">
                    <div style="float: right; margin-top: -8px; margin-right: 10px">
                        <button id="contacttrigger" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle btn-lg contact-trigger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></button>
                        <%--<img id="contacttrigger" src="Content/Images/icon-contact.png">--%>
                        <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" ID="loginView">
                            <LoggedInTemplate>
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/UserConfig.aspx" title="Manage your account">
                                        <div style="float: left">
                                            <div class="avatar-container" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; margin-top: -5px">
                                                <img class="avatar" runat="server" id="loginAvatar" src="" style="height: 30px; width: 30px" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px; color: #333">
                                            Hei <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </LoggedInTemplate>
                        </asp:LoginView>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, with corresponding media queries and/or extra selectors to affect only responsive and/or only iPhone, as precise as you need:

```
.collapse.in {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```